# java.nio.file.Path: creating a path for a different/virtual FileSystem?

Tags: java, path, filesystems

I am using `java.nio.file.Path` for modifying paths that do not exist in file-system, but inside a ZIP file. Of course I can not use such `Path` instances for reading and writing file content but that is not a problem in my context, I just need it e.g. to call `getParent()` `getFileName()` or `getNameCount()`.

Usually this works well but now I encountered a ZIP file that uses `|` for certain paths in the ZIP file. If I try to parse such paths using `Paths.get(pathInZip)` results in an `java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <|> at index ...`.

Is there a way to tell `Path` that it is not a path in the current file-system of the OS and therefore it is not limited by e.g. the reserved characters for the OS file-system?

Or is using `java.nio.file.Path` the wrong approach here?

Comment: `Path` is an interface. You are using the wrong approach if you rely on the default filesystem to provide and manipulate Path instances for a zip -`Path.of(x)` uses `FileSystems.getDefault()`. Instances of Path provided by the Zip File System should deal with the case you have, as suggested by k314159.

Comment: The problem is that you need a ZIP file for doing so, but I don't have a ZIP file, only a file that was once saved in a ZIP file and the file path it had when it was saved in the ZIP file, and I don't have access to the ZIP file, I only get this data.

Answer (score 1):

You should be reading the contents of the zip file using the [Zip File System](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html). Then you will be able to use a Path that understands all the characters that are allowed to be part of a name in a zip file. For example, the following lists the contents of the top-level directories of a given zip file:

```
    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(Path.of(zipfile))) {
        for (Path directory : fs.getRootDirectories()) {
            System.out.println(directory);
            Files.list(directory).forEach(path -> System.out.println("\t" + path));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The ZIP is on a different server in a different Java process, I am just processing some extracted files from the ZIP and in addition I have the path from within the ZIP file. Based on the path I can get important information. Therefore the Zip File System is of no help to me.

Comment: In that case, I would look at DuncG's answer. If that doesn't work for you, maybe just treat the filename as a string and do things like `filename.split("/")` to get its parts.

Answer (score 1):

I won't recommend using this answer but you could have a look at whether creating a dummy ZIP file provides you access to zip filesystem `Path` for any path manipulation you need.

Here is a snippet of code I tried in jshell:

```
// Create a path to a zip
Path zip = Files.createTempFile(Path.of(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")), "xx", ".zip")

// Make sure it doesn't exist
Files.delete(zip);

// Create ZIP FS (should use try with resources here)
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zip, Map.of("create","true"))

// See if you can make your path manipulation work:
Path x = fs.getPath("/some/path|abc/withanotherbar|here")
==> /some/path|abc/withanotherbar|here

Path parent = x.getParent()
parent ==> /some/path|abc

Path name = x.getFileName()
name ==> withanotherbar|here

int parts = x.getNameCount()
parts ==> 3

Path y = fs.getPath("relative/some/path|andbar/withabar|here")
==> relative/some/path|andbar/withabar|here

Path yParent = y.getParent()
==> relative/some/path|andbar

int yc = y.getNameCount()
==> 4
```

Note that the Paths `x` or `parent` from Zip Filesystem above would be no use to you for filesystem access, but you might be able to use `toString()` to get the path component in a form which you might use in your other (unspecified) code.

Comment: Sorry, but creating a temporary file just for parsing some paths doesn't seem to me like good programming style. Why should I waste time on disk I/O just to parse/process a a String? Even implementing an own dummy `FileSystemProvider` would be a way better way.

Comment: That's why I said "I won't recommend using this answer".